# Round corners for custom bezierPath shape

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mask, uibezierpath

I wanted to draw a triangle with rounded corners in my app.
I already created a triangle like this:

[image: Example]

How can I round the corners of this triangle?

**Here is my code:**

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 160, y: 90))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 180))
path.close()
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
triangleView.layer.mask = triangleLayer
```

*Thanks for any kind of help :D*

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using an image instead?

Comment: You would have to add a bezier curve to the corners...

Comment: Yeah @nathan, I could use an image but that would enlarge the size of my app and is not very flexible.

Comment: @Sulthan Could you give an example please? :)

Comment: You can insert arbitrary arcs into your path with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624367-addarc. For your needs this is a little bit complicate. You have to compute the angels and center points of the arcs, and the new start and end points of the lines.

Comment: @Gamecraftler I would recommend using an image. Your app payload would be larger — but by an insignificant amount. What do you mean by not flexible? Are you planning on animating the shape's path?

Comment: @nathan I mean, when I want to change the aspect ratio or something else, I'd have to go to photoshop, change it, and reload it in my app.

Comment: @Gamecraftler Use the workflow that's best for you. Just so you know, to get rounded corners you're going to have to add a lot more code, which will become more difficult to modify as it grows in complexity. Going back and forth between a design tool and Xcode is much easier in my experience.